# What does the "first hit props" message do?

Tags: mortal-kombat-11

In Mk11, when one character hits another with an attack, being the first one,  it gives a message saying "first hit props". Does this have any benefit to the player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it does anything. In MkX, you get an extra bar meter but in Mk11 you start off with all 4 bars.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you points, and some Brutalities only work if you landed the first hit.